# What's my public IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, ipv4

I ran this command in Windows: `ipconfig`. And it gave me this:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9d15:5458:ade0:f388%48
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.25.176.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6e6d:845d:33f7:433a%51
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.25.224.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2402:d000:8100:3638:d229:fad7:3abb:6299
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2402:d000:8100:3638:1456:4bc4:54b0:95ad
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f43f:213e:60e1:3cff%5
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%5
                                       192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c1eb:555b:ee1b:1767%59
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Where is my public IP address????

Comment: On the WAN port of your router.

Comment: there is nothing called wan only lan

Comment: What kind/model of router do you have?

Comment: how to find router type

Comment: a) Visit 192.168.1.1 and see what brand it shows, 2) Look at the sticker on the bottom

Comment: Huawei HG8245H5

Comment: Does it have "Advanced → System → Device Information"?

Comment: The LAN port is the one connecting your PC. The WAN port is the one connecting to your ISP.

Answer (score 2):

Simple but effective zero code solution…
Go to Google [or the search engine of your choice] & type "What's my IP address?"

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Your computer's public **IPv6** address is shown as "IPv6 Address", it's the `2402:d000:<...>:6299` one.

Your computer's public **IPv4** address is not shown because your computer **doesn't have one.**

There's a shortage of IPv4 addresses, so residential ISPs issue as few of them as they can get away with – practically always the ISP only issues you one address at most, and that address gets assigned **to the router**. (It's not "shared" with the entire LAN – it belongs exclusively to the router that it's assigned to. The router's NAT function just rewrites packets going through it to make it *look like* they came from the router's address.)

So in order to find the address you have, you'll need to check your router's settings screens. On many Huawei routers/modems, the "WAN IP Address" can usually be found under `Advanced > System > Device Information`.

Note though that increasingly more ISPs no longer give customers a public IPv4 address *at all,* i.e. not even the router has one anymore, with the ISP putting it behind a second layer of NAT (i.e. "CGNAT"). If your router shows an 100.64.x.x – 100.127.x.x address, that's a private address as well; the "real" public address stays on the ISP's side.

Answer (score -1):

Go to https://api.ipify.org

(something to avoid 30 chars limit)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).